# Group instance: move source group

Tags: python, transforms, groups, instances, data-blocks

I've created a group then group instance and moved the parent. The result is that instances move in very strange way, like theyre movement s summing with parent or something...

What is happening? I need to create some instances of object, rotate them and then move them with source to some position

Comment: I see, that I should use linked duplicate not group instance: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15728/local-anchor-for-group-master-move-translate-offset-of-group-master-moves-group?rq=1