# Change Group Pivot Point

Tags: workflow

I think the Problem is relatively simple, but if i google "Set Group Pivot" or "Set Group Origin" always found "Pivot of Object" solutions.  I have 2 Group Instances, "Rack 1" and "Rack 2". Both Racks are made of a couple of connectors which are also Group Instances. Now i would like to set the Pivot Point of Rack 2 (2) to the same Position as the Pivot Point of Rack 1 (1), to the lower left Corner (3). It must be possible to make because the Pivot Point of Rack 1 (1) is in the lower left Corner. How can i do this?

[image: Group Pivot Points]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15728/local-anchor-for-group-master-move-translate-offset-of-group-master-moves-group. To move that origin point move the objects which are group masters to the global scene center (but maybe in another file); no other way afaik.

Comment: thank you, that save my day. (PS: Rack 2 is located in an other layer)